# How to sort an ArrayList by comparing the element's property?

Tags: java, collections

Hi I'm new to Java I got a ArrayList `[object1, object2...]`

and each object has a `getNumber()` methods, which returns a int number

How can I sort the ArrayList by comparing the return value of getNumber() method?

Comment: Use [`Collections#sort(List, Comparator)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29)

Comment: And [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) or [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html):

```
// Here T is your class name
public class Test implements Comparator<T> {
   @Override
    public int compare(T o1, T o2) {
        return (o1.getNumber() - o2.getNumber());
   }    
}
```

And pass it to  [Collections.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29):

```
Collections.sort(yourList, new Test());
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a comparator or implement comparable on your Arraylist objects

http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator

Above link should have everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Comparator and Collections.sort()
Make sure the [equals()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) and [hashCode()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) methods of the object you store in the ArrayList are overriden properly and respect the hashCode contract.

You can have a look to [this article](http://www.vogella.com/blog/2009/08/04/collections-sort-java/) for more details.

Comment: You don't need `equals` nor `hashCode` when using `Collections#sort`.

Comment: From the javadoc of Comparable:
It is strongly recommended (though not required) that natural orderings be consistent with equals. This is so because sorted sets (and sorted maps) without explicit comparators behave "strangely" when they are used with elements (or keys) whose natural ordering is inconsistent with equals. In particular, such a sorted set (or sorted map) violates the general contract for set (or map), which is defined in terms of the equals method.